# Using .apply in pandas library and getting "np not callable" error

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to apply my dispersion function :

```
def disp_calc(returns, p, wi):    #apply(disp_calc, rows = ...)
    wi = wi/np.sum(wi)
    ri_p = returns_stock.subtract(p,axis=0)    
    rp = np.nansum(wi*((ri_p)**2))
    return np.sqrt(rp)
```

To my returns_sector df below:

```
for i in sectors: 
    returns_sector = returns[sectordict[i]]                  
    pr = returns[sectordict[i]].apply(np.mean,axis=1)         
    w = newmerge.Weight[newmerge.SectorSymbol == i]        
    disp_df[date] = returns_sector.apply(disp_calc(returns_sector,pr,w),axis=1)
```

I keep getting the `error` :

```
TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 2017-01-03 00:00:00')
```

I've never had this problem with apply before and not really sure what I'm doing wrong. My expected output is to apply the disperson function to all the values in my `returns_sector df`.

Comment: It seems some `NaN`s values, can you check it?

Comment: yeah there are some Nan values im using rolling(21)

Comment: returns[sectordict[i]]  this is a value,not an array

Comment: what do you mean? when I do type() it says its a df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly passing arguments to your `disp_calc` function. Try this:

```
disp_df[date] = returns_sector.apply(disp_calc, args=(pr, w), axis=1)
```

The calling dataframe is automatically passed as the first argument to the function.

The error your're seeing is that your current first argument to `apply()` is the float returned by `disp_calc()`, which is not a function, and thus not a callable. Pandas expects the first argument in the `apply()` function to be callable.

Comment: thanks, wasn't sure how to go about dealing with the "tuple" because I had three args